# Moving stuff off of SSD to HDD after installation. Using mount --bind? LiveCD?

Tags: mount, partition, ssd

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my SSD. /dev/sda1. No other partitions. No swap.

Then I went about reading how to optimize usage, and have come to the conclusion I want my /home, /var and /tmp mounted on my hard disk drive. I don't have it mounted yet, but I have a line in my fstab that lists the UUID of my HDD and has it (/dev/sdb1) mounted in /media/hdd. Hard disk too, no partitions. Just plain disk space.

I do *NOT* want to create partitions on either my SSD or HDD. All I want however, is to *move* my /tmp, /home and /var partitions to my HDD.

What are my options to do this cleanly, preferably without using a LiveCD to login? (I am imagining I could use a LiveCD, literally do

```
mv /home /media/hdd/home
ln -s /media/hdd/home /home

mv /var /media/hdd/var
ln -s /media/hdd/var /var

mv /tmp /media/hdd/tmp
ln -s /media/hdd/tmp /tmp
```

What about permissions?

Is my thinking correct? Can I somehow use a mount --bind option to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you described in your question is going to be the only way I know how to do this without creating individual partitions on your HDD.

Comment: All right, I will just go with that. Thanks !